# Why is statsmodels package not working on Flask but is on ipython?

Tags: flask, scipy, statsmodels

I am getting this import error from the scipy package. Please see requirements.txt for versions. This is only happening on Flask and not when I run the same code on ipython. Is there any reason why statsmodels doesn't work on flask but would work on ipython?

```
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/api.py", line 9, in
from . import regression
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/init.py", line 1, in
from .linear_model import yule_walker
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 39, in
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/init.py", line 156, in
from . import fft
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fft/init.py", line 81, in
from ._helper import next_fast_len
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fft/_helper.py", line 4, in
from . import _pocketfft
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/init.py", line 3, in
from .basic import *
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/basic.py", line 8, in
from . import pypocketfft as pfft
ImportError: SystemExit: 1
```

*This happens only in Flask. When i use statsmodels

I'm running it in flask and here are my complete list of packages:

```
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.5
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
cachetools==4.0.0
cattrs==1.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloudstorage==0.10.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.1
defusedxml==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.3
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Assets==2.0
Flask-CacheBuster==1.0.0
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
flask-talisman==0.7.0
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-auth==1.11.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==1.2.0
google-cloud-storage==1.25.0
google-cloud-tasks==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.26.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
inflect==3.0.2
inflection==0.3.1
ipykernel==5.1.4
ipython==7.11.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.16.0
Jinja2==2.11.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.4
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1
jupyter-core==4.6.1
jupyter-highlight-selected-word==0.2.0
jupyter-latex-envs==1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator==0.4.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
looker-sdk==0.1.3b6
lxml==4.5.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.2
mistune==0.8.4
natural==0.2.0
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.4
nltk==3.4.5
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==0.25.3
pandas-datareader==0.8.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.6.0
patsy==0.5.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pg8000==1.13.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.3
protobuf==3.11.2
psycopg2==2.8.4
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.5.0
Pygments==2.5.2
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyrsistent==0.15.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-magic==0.4.15
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3
pyzmq==18.1.1
qtconsole==4.6.0
requests==2.22.0
rsa==4.0
scipy==1.4.1
scramp==1.1.0
seasonal==0.3.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simple-salesforce==0.74.3
simplenlg==0.2.0
six==1.14.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
statsmodels==0.11.0
stripe==2.42.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
tornado==6.0.3
traitlets==4.3.3
tzlocal==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.8
wcwidth==0.1.8
webapp2==2.5.2
webassets==2.0
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.16.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
zipp==2.1.0
```

no error in ipython, but i get an error when i run it in flask

Comment: What version of python are you using to run your Flask app?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4654) issues for more detail.

Turns out that `statsmodels` is dependent upon several packages being installed before it so that it can key on them to compile its own modules. Although I don't exactly know what causes this particular conflict with `flask`, I have faced this on `python3.7` before and here is what worked for me:

If you need to clean out what you already have, you can uninstall with the following command:

```
pip3 uninstall statsmodels
```

Now install `Flask`

```
pip3 install Flask
```

Install the individual dependencies of `statmodels` first:

```
pip3 install numpy scipy patsy pandas
```

Now install `statmodels`:

```
pip3 install statsmodels
```

**Important!!!**

- Make sure you are running a fresh virtual environment. To open a new one in linxux system:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

- Now install the dependencies as instructed above. Let me know if that fixed your problem. If not, you might need a better dependency resolver than `pip`. [Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the server and the problem is solved!